# jquery switch between two views

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I got two divs with the id's `today` and `tomorrow`. As only one of them can be shown, I wrote a javascript function which switches between those two.

```
    function switchDay(selector) {
    if (selector == "tomorrow") {
        $("#today").hide();
        $("#tomorrow").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('<a href="#" onclick="return switchDay(\'today\');">this day</a> | next day');

    }
    if (selector == "today") {
        $("#tomorrow").hide();
        $("#today").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('this day | <a href="#" onclick="return switchDay(\'tomorrow\');">next day</a>');

    }   
  return false;
}
```

In my PHP I echo the switch links like this:

```
echo '<p id="daySelector">today | <a href="#" onclick="return switchDay(\'tomorrow\');">tomorrow</a></p>';
```

As you can see, I already switched hide() and show() to jquery functions (before I was using .style.display functions) and would now like to also ditch the old `onclick` and rather use the jquery `.click()`. Though, I am not sure how I would change the switch links.

How can I do this? (Best would be if it didn't make my script bigger by much...)

Comment: Seems like you have some weird logic going on... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: He's trying to toggle the displayed div and update the link that toggles the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many approaches to this (God, I love programming because of this).

An easy one would be to do this:

```
$('#daySelector a').live('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("tomorrow")) {
        $("#today").hide();
        $("#tomorrow").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('<a href="#" class="today">this day</a> | next day');    
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("today")) {
        $("#tomorrow").hide();
        $("#today").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('this day | <a href="#" class="tomorrow">next day</a>');

    }   
  return false;
});
```

Then just do the PHP like this:

```
echo '<p id="daySelector">today | <a href="#" class="tomorrow">tomorrow</a></p>';
```

I didn't test it. Should still work.

Following a comment below that reminded me of live being deprecated. Here's how it would be using .on method. I edited too avoiding usage of document for the binding.

```
$('#daySelector').on('click', 'a', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("tomorrow")) {
        $("#today").hide();
        $("#tomorrow").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('<a href="#" class="today">this day</a> | next day');    
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("today")) {
        $("#tomorrow").hide();
        $("#today").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('this day | <a href="#" class="tomorrow">next day</a>');

    }   
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Overall, your solution is much more elegant than the one I proposed. My solution was meant considering his already existing logic. Your refactoring was better :)

Comment: binding to `#daySelector` would be more ideal than the `document`

Comment: I don't think `class` is the ideal way to identify the selector.  `class` should keep its use reserved for css styling.

Comment: You may want to add in a preventDefault so the page doesn't jump to the top :)

Comment: @Bankzilla `return false` is the classic Javascript way to prevent the anchor from being followed, so that is basically covered (though maybe not in jQuery fashion).

Comment: @Mamsaac Thanks, I was trying to demonstrate that the Javascript need not be so tightly coupled to specific CSS class name or IDs, as any "variables" can be fetched from DOM attributes (eg. 'data-div'). There is always room for improvement though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the click handler from the link, add a selector attribute:

```
echo '<p id="daySelector">today | <a href="#" selector="tomorrow">tomorrow</a></p>';
```

Add a click handler:

```
$('#daySelector').on('click','a', function() {
    return switchDay(this.attr("selector"));
});
```

It should be noted that [`live` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of 1.7

```
function switchDay(selector) {
    if (selector == "tomorrow") {
        $("#today").hide();
        $("#tomorrow").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('<a href="#" selector="today">this day</a> | next day');

    } else if (selector == "today") {
        $("#tomorrow").hide();
        $("#today").show();
        $("#daySelector").html('this day | <a href="#" selector="tomorrow">next day</a>');

    }   
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delegate the event to the parent element and you can get rid of the if/else because [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) allows you to pass in a condition - true=show/false=hide..

```
$('#daySelector').on('click','a',function(e){    
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor click action
    var day = $(this).text();  // get text to check
    $("#tomorrow").toggle(day.indexOf('this') > -1); // show if currently this
    $("#today").toggle(day.indexOf('next') > -1); // show if currently next
    $(this).text(day.indexOf('this') > -1 ? 'next day':'this day'); // toggle text
});​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFDsZ/

I was just guessing some parts as you didn't show all your html.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Markup:

```
<div id='today'>Content A</div>
<div id='tomorrow'>Content B</div>
<p><a href="#" id='switch'>Switch to <span id='switchText'>tomorrow</span></a></p>
```

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        showToday();
        $('#switch').click(
            function () {
                var switchText = $('#switchText').text();
                if (switchText == 'tomorrow') {
                    showTomorrow();
                } else {
                    showToday();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    );
    function showToday() {
        $('#today').show();
        $('#tomorrow').hide();
        $('#switchText').text('tomorrow');
    }

    function showTomorrow() {
        $('#today').hide();
        $('#tomorrow').show();
        $('#switchText').text('today');
    }
```